# Function Defined in Before Block Not Finishing Before Tests Run in Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am creating some tests using Mocha/Chai in my Node project. In one particular test I need to first save a `document` to the database, then later retrieve it and run some checks on the found document.

The problem I'm running into is that the `it` checks are running before the document is finished being saved to the database. I don't understand why this is happening because I am doing the saving in the `before()` block -- which, according to the Mocha documentation, should run before the tests in that same describe block, see below from the documentation:

```
> With its default "BDD"-style interface, Mocha provides the hooks
> before(), after(), beforeEach(), and afterEach(). These should be used
> to set up preconditions and clean up after your tests.
> 
> describe('hooks', function() {   before(function() {
>     // runs before all tests in this block   });
> 
>   after(function() {
>     // runs after all tests in this block   });
> 
>   beforeEach(function() {
>     // runs before each test in this block   });
> 
>   afterEach(function() {
>     // runs after each test in this block   });
> 
>   // test cases });
```

To clarify, when I run the test a second time (and all subsequent times), all checks pass, because by then it can find the document in the db.

What am I missing here?

Here is my code:

```
const assert = require("chai").assert;
const expect = require("chai").expect;
const chai = require("chai");
chai.use(require("chai-datetime"));
const Agenda = require('agenda');

const config = require('./../../configuration');
const url = config.get('MONGO_URL');
const dbName = config.get('MONGO_DATABASE');
const collection = config.get('MONGO_COLLECTION');
const createAgendaJob = require('./../../lib/agenda-jobs/contact-firstname-to-proper-case');

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const client = new MongoClient(url);

describe("Contact FirstName to Proper Case", async function () {
  const jobName = "Contact FirstName To Proper Case";
  const testDate = new Date(2019, 01, 01);
  let result;
  let agenda;
  this.timeout(2000);
  before(async function () {
    const connectionOpts = {
      db: {
        address: `${url}/${dbName}`,
        collection
      }
    };

    agenda = new Agenda(connectionOpts);
    await new Promise(resolve => agenda.once('ready', resolve));
    await createAgendaJob(agenda); // Here is where I save the job to the DB
  });
  client.connect(async function (err) {
    assert.equal(null, err);

    const db = await client.db(dbName);

    result = await db.collection("jobs").findOne({
      "name": jobName
    });

    client.close();
  });
  it("should have a property 'name'", function () {
    expect(result).to.have.property("name");
  });
  it("should have a 'name' of 'Contact FirstName To Proper Case'", function () {
    expect(result.name).to.equal("Contact FirstName To Proper Case");
  });
  it("should have a property 'type'", function () {
    expect(result).to.have.property("type");
  });
  it("should have a 'type' of 'normal'", function () {
    expect(result.type).to.equal("normal");
  });
  it("should have a property 'repeatTimezone'", function () {
    expect(result).to.have.property("repeatTimezone");
  });
  it("should have a property 'repeatInterval'", function () {
    expect(result).to.have.property("repeatInterval");
  });
  it("should have a property 'lastModifiedBy'", function () {
    expect(result).to.have.property("lastModifiedBy");
  });
  it("should have a property 'nextRunAt'", function () {
    expect(result).to.have.property("nextRunAt");
  });
  it("should return a date for the 'nextRunAt' property", function () {
    assert.typeOf(result.nextRunAt, "date");
  });
  it("should 'nextRunAt' to be a date after test date", function () {
    expect(result.nextRunAt).to.afterDate(testDate);
  });
});
```

I also tried putting the `it` checks in a subsequent `describe()` block, but this also didn't work (same result -- doc is only found on SECOND run of the test file):

```
const assert = require("chai").assert;
const expect = require("chai").expect;
const chai = require("chai");
chai.use(require("chai-datetime"));
const Agenda = require('agenda');

const config = require('./../../configuration');
const url = config.get('MONGO_URL');
const dbName = config.get('MONGO_DATABASE');
const collection = config.get('MONGO_COLLECTION');
const createAgendaJob = require('./../../lib/agenda-jobs/contact-firstname-to-proper-case');

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const client = new MongoClient(url);

describe("Contact FirstName to Proper Case", async function () {
  const jobName = "Contact FirstName To Proper Case";
  const testDate = new Date(2019, 01, 01);
  let result;
  let agenda;
  this.timeout(2000);
  before(async function () {
    const connectionOpts = {
      db: {
        address: `${url}/${dbName}`,
        collection
      }
    };

    agenda = new Agenda(connectionOpts);
    await new Promise(resolve => agenda.once('ready', resolve));
    await createAgendaJob(agenda); // Here is where I save the job to the DB
  });
  client.connect(async function (err) {
    assert.equal(null, err);

    const db = await client.db(dbName);

    result = await db.collection("jobs").findOne({
      "name": jobName
    });

    client.close();
  });
  describe("Check Contact FirstName To ProperCase Found Job", function () {
    it("should have a property 'name'", function () {
      expect(result).to.have.property("name");
    });
    it("should have a 'name' of 'Contact FirstName To Proper Case'", function () {
      expect(result.name).to.equal("Contact FirstName To Proper Case");
    });
    it("should have a property 'type'", function () {
      expect(result).to.have.property("type");
    });
    it("should have a 'type' of 'normal'", function () {
      expect(result.type).to.equal("normal");
    });
    it("should have a property 'repeatTimezone'", function () {
      expect(result).to.have.property("repeatTimezone");
    });
    it("should have a property 'repeatInterval'", function () {
      expect(result).to.have.property("repeatInterval");
    });
    it("should have a property 'lastModifiedBy'", function () {
      expect(result).to.have.property("lastModifiedBy");
    });
    it("should have a property 'nextRunAt'", function () {
      expect(result).to.have.property("nextRunAt");
    });
    it("should return a date for the 'nextRunAt' property", function () {
      assert.typeOf(result.nextRunAt, "date");
    });
    it("should 'nextRunAt' to be a date after test date", function () {
      expect(result.nextRunAt).to.afterDate(testDate);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `it` running before `before` finished, but this is ran before everything:

```
    client.connect(async function (err) {
     ...
    });
```

Mocha, when creates test suide runs code like this:

- call each function that is passed to `describe`

  - collect all `it`s and `before/after*` hooks
  - that's when your `client.connect` snippet is actually called!
- then, after whole suite/test tree is created, for each suite

  - call apropriate before* hooks
  - call all `it`s - tests, possibly surrounded by `before/afterAll` hooks
  - call `after` hooks

Each hook / test run waits for finish at least in your case, as you use async/await properly

Also, note that this is very fishy:

```
await setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('finished pausing for 5 seconds...');
}, 5000);
```

This doesn't wait for anything, because `setTimeout` returns timer it (number possibly) and it's not well defined what `await` should do with this data as this is not promise.
For sure, it doesn't wait 5 seconds.

Proper promised wait looks as follows:

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))
```